# Is there a rule/s for determining whether a contradiciton is a Dialetheia?

Tags: logic, dialectic, paraconsistency, dialetheism

If not, is there a set of accepted properties or qualities that dialetheic statements have?

Comment: Hi there, welcome aboard! At risk of asking something that probably seems a bit silly, do you mean more than just "that as well as being false, they are also true"?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for something along the lines of "contradictions of this form 'p' are dialetheia", or if the output of this algorithm is 'x' then this contradiction is a dialetheia.

Comment: Formally, any contradiction is a dialetheia, both true and false. However, this is interesting only when the formal system does not derive that every statement is a contradiction, which classical systems do if they derive at least one. Thus, which statements end up as dialetheias in non-classical systems depends on *informal* wishes of their designers, so there are no "accepted properties". But some paradigmatic examples are [listed by SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/#OtheMotiForDial): self-referential paradoxes, transitional states, borderline cases, legal collisions, etc.

Comment: Offhand, based on a very incomplete survey of the literature, I would say that my only impression of a unifying theme, here, is that dialetheias are acceptable when their conjuncts are independently derived. Axiomatic dialetheias don't seem to be proposed (to my knowledge). The liar paradox is a difficult case vs. this picture of things, though (is the base sentence itself advanced as if it were an axiom? or at least a hypothesis? and how does attaching truth or falsity to the base "from the outside" avoid dialogically *transforming* that base?).

Comment: Is it correct to say that Dialetheia have no identifying characteristics other than they can be interpreted as being both 'true' and 'false'?

Comment: This is one of those rare occasions when I disagree with @Conifold. If a theory is closed under an explosive logic, such as classical logic, then an inconsistent theory includes all sentences as theorems. But this does not mean that all sentences are true; one should not conflate truth with theoremhood. Model theory for classical logic assigns a valuation false to any contradiction...

Comment: The dialethist maintains that some, but not all, contradictions are true, and these true contradictions are dialetheia. Whether any given contradiction is a dialetheia must be argued for, e.g. on semantic or pragmatic grounds. A dialetheia does not have *formal* identifying characteristics.